# How to use a specified topic in a saga when using MassTransit on Azure ServiceBus

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I would like all the messaging for a particular saga to all take place on the same topic.

I set my saga up like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        var machine = new MyStateMachine();
        var repository = new InMemorySagaRepository<MyState>();

        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx,cfg) => {
            cfg.Host(config.ServiceBusConnectionString);

            cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("mySub", "myTopic", e =>
            {
                e.StateMachineSaga(machine, repository);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

In the state machine I do this:

```
Initially(
   When(FirstEvent)
   .PublishAsync(context => context.Init<SecondMessage>(new { TestParam = "test"}))
   .TransitionTo(FirstState));
```

I would like the SecondMessage to be published on the topic 'myTopic' but instead MassTransit creates a new topic for this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit creates a topic per message type, and publishes messages to their corresponding topics. Assigning the same topic name to multiple message types is not recommended.

If you want to use a subscription endpoint for a saga, you would need to configure the saga on the corresponding topic for each event. By default, MassTransit will forward the message topics for each saga event to the receive endpoint queue.

An example topology is shown below:

[image: Azure Service Bus Topology]